# Iterating through a list of tuples with Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a list of tuples

```
   list =  [(1,2,4),(4,1,4),(3,7,2),(4,2,5),(1,5,9)]
```

I'd like to iterate through the list and get each tuple by itself. 
For ex, maybe print

```
(1,2,3)

(4,1,4)

(3,7,2)
```

and so on.

I'm having trouble accessing the items in the list because if I were to do `list!!1`, I can't access all the other elements after if I try `list!!3`.

How would one approach iterating through a list of tuples with haskell?

Comment: those are tuples in the list.

Comment: It's a list of 3-tuples, not a list of lists.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I've edited my post to reflect my mistake

Comment: What resource are you using to learn Haskell? I would recommend reading about pattern matching on lists and recursion. Then you can try using e.g. map or mapM, then you might try implementing those two functions yourself

Comment: How about `mapM_ print [(1,2,4),(4,1,4),(3,7,2),(4,2,5),(1,5,9)]`

Comment: `(!!)` isn't needed that often in Haskell. If you need to pick and choose specific elements of a list, it's a good sign you should be using a product type instead of a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't specific to lists of *tuples*, what you need is knowing how to iterate through a list of anything.

Traditionally, since you don't have loops, "iterating" in functional languages is done through recursion so a reasonable first solution would look like :

```
printAList [] = return ()
printAList (x:xs) = do
  print x
  printAList xs
```

but of course, writing a recursion every time you want to go through a list is silly so all functional languages contain *higher order functions* that takes a function in parameter to indicate what to do with each element of a list and how to combine the results. Such a function that is often seen is `map` which create a new list with the results of the passed function on each element :

```
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

So here you might think to do `map print yourList`. Unfortunately, `print` doesn't really show its argument, it is a function that creates an IO action that, when executed, would show the argument. So you'll get a list of actions with your map and to execute it, you'll have to use the function that executes a list of actions : `sequence_` (the _ indicates we don't care about the returns of each action)

```
sequence_ [] = return ()
sequence_ (act : acts) = do
  act
  sequence_ acts
```

So your final code would be `sequence_ (map print yourList)`. Of course, applying an action creating function to the element of a list and executing them is a sufficiently frequent need that you have a dedicated function for that : `mapM_` (the M indicates that this is the "monadic" version of map and the _ that we throw out the results after execution).

```
mapM_ f xs = sequence_ (map f xs)
```

TL:DR So to show each of your tuple you just have to write `mapM_ print yourList`.

Comment: `mapM_` can also be replaced with `traverse_ print xs`—or its flipped cousin, `for_ xs print`—which can be used in more places because they only require an `Applicative` constraint instead of `Monad`. Same goes for the versions of these functions without `_`, which accumulate results. `mapM` is a historical artifact from before `Applicative` was made a superclass of `Monad`.

Comment: You're right of course, though should I replace sequence_ by sequenceA_ ? I would probably still give the list version of those functions (just adding a remark to the effect that those functions work with some other "containers")